# sort NSMutableArray using special pattern?

Tags: objective-c, programming-languages, ios4

I want to sort an array something like this.

Suppose I have 4 users they log into their device like this

User 1 device (user id's 1,2,3,4)

User 2 device (user id's 1,2,3,4)

User 3 device (user id's 1,2,3,4)

User 4 device (user id's 1,2,3,4)

Now I want them to be sorted like this in each of their devices like clockwise.

User 1 device (user id's 1,2,3,4)

User 2 device (user id's 2,3,4,1)

User 3 device (user id's 3,4,1,2)

User 4 device (user id's 4,1,2,3)

Does someone knows any algorithm to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to remove the first item of the array and then add it to the end and continue until the the user see's their username/id. This may work because as you remove the first item they are all shifted down to the first spot.

```
while([[array objectAtIndex:0] id] != [user id])
{
    id temp = [[array objectAtIndex:0] retain];
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:0]; //may cause a deallocation of "temp" if it weren't retained
    [array addObject:temp];
    [temp release];
}
```

Comment: @cwieland there were some programmatic errors in your sample, which i've corrected.  The overall idea seems correct, though. :)

Comment: Yeah i guess I should have stated it was sudo code. Thanks for making it usable. props!

Comment: @cwieland,@Dace DeLong
Thanks to you guys. Let me see if it works.Thank you very much

Comment: Stuck when I do not have object in the array corresponding to my Id. By the Way I solved the problem thank you guys.

Comment: @cwieland  I'll post my code on Monday. By the way First I check in array of users that if(myIdExists) { then run the while loop} otherwise do not run while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an NSArray according to any criteria you like.  See `-sortUsingComparator:` or `-sortUsingFunction:`, for example.

Comment: I want the above pattern. Unable to create comparator/sortUsingFunction could you please do this?